# COMPSs runcompss error. Can't run the matmul example app locally

Tags: java, runtime-error, distributed-computing, hpc

I have recently started using COMPSs. I am following one of the documentation examples, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am trying to run the provided matmul example app and I am using this command:

```
runcompss --classpath=./matmul.jar matmul.files.Matmul 4 1
```

However, I get the following output:

```
Using default location for project file: /opt/COMPSs/Runtime/scripts/user/../../configuration/xml/projects/project.xml

Using default location for resources file: /opt/COMPSs/Runtime/scripts/user/../../configuration/xml/resources/resources.xml

----------------- Executing matmul.files.Matmul --------------------------

WARNING: IT Properties file is null. Setting default values
[   API]  -  Deploying COMPSs Runtime v1.4 (build 20160302-1306)
[   API]  -  Starting COMPSs Runtime v1.4 (build 20160302-1306)
[   API]  -  No more tasks for app 1
[ERRMGR]  -  WARNING: Task 'multiplyAccumulative' with job id 1 FAILED in worker 'localhost'.
                      Resubmitting job to same worker.
[ERRMGR]  -  WARNING: Task 'multiplyAccumulative' with job id 3 FAILED in worker 'localhost'.
                      Resubmitting job to same worker.
[ERRMGR]  -  WARNING: Task 'multiplyAccumulative' with job id 2 FAILED in worker 'localhost'.
                      Resubmitting job to same worker.
[ERRMGR]  -  WARNING: Task 'multiplyAccumulative' with job id 4 FAILED in worker 'localhost'.
                      Resubmitting job to same worker.
[ERRMGR]  -  WARNING: Task 'multiplyAccumulative' with job id 1 FAILED in worker 'localhost' after resubmit.
                      Rescheduling job. (Changing worker)
[ERRMGR]  -  ERROR:   Task 'multiplyAccumulative' TOTALLY FAILED.
                      Possible causes:
                           -Exception thrown by task 'multiplyAccumulative'.
                           -Expected output files not generated by task 'multiplyAccumulative'.
                           -Could not provide nor retrieve needed data between master and worker.

                      Check files '/home/vanton/.COMPSs/matmul.files.Matmul_08/jobs/job1_[NEW|RESUBMITTED|RESCHEDULED].[out|err]' to find out the error.

[ERRMGR]  -  Shutting down COMPSs...
[   API]  -  Execution Finished

Error running application
```

What could be causing this error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classpath option must be an **absolute path** to your jar file.

For example, if the matmul.jar is located under the `$HOME/workspace_java/matmul/jar/` path, you should execute:

```
runcompss -d --classpath=$HOME/workspace_java/matmul/jar/matmul.jar matmul.files.Matmul 4 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something wrong is happening in the execution of tasks. Have you checked the runtime.log or the standard out/err of the task?

Comment: Where are those files? The output says they are supposed to be in this directory ''/home/vanton/.COMPSs/matmul.files.Matmul_08/jobs/", but there's nothing there, the directory does not even exist...

Comment: You have to run with the debug option: `runcompss -d`

Comment: You can enable the debugging logs by passing a CLI argument to the execution. Unix format: `runcompss -d`. GNU format: `runcompss --debug=debug_level` where debug_level = [off | info | debug]

Comment: Oh now I see the files!
There's an error printed there:
   integratedtoolkit.nio.exceptions.JobExecutionException: Can not get class by reflection
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: matmul.files.MatmulImpl